# PHP get same day of same week next year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm working on a client scheduler and my employer wants it to automatically reschedule clients each year. He wants them to keep the same day of the same week every year.

For example, a client is scheduled for May 23rd 2014. This is the fourth friday of may. Once May 23rd 2014 has passed, a appointment for the fourth friday of may in 2015 should be booked (in this case the 22nd).

I've tried various things to get this to work (such as using DateTime to advance by a year and find "previous" of whatever day of the week it was). But every model I've tried breaks down a bit after just a few years. They'll end up on like...the second Friday of the month.

Does anyone have a way to get this to work? My employer is very specific about wanting the scheduler to work this way. x.x I'd really appreciate the help if someone knows how.

Thanks for reading this!

Comment: instead of storing "may 23rd 2014" in the db, store the actual rule: "4th friday of may". then you can use some DateTime() math to calculate that for any given year.

Comment: Don't rely on `strtotime` or `DateTime` correctly understanding `"next Friday"` or some such correctly every time. Do your own time math using these libraries. Start at the first of the same month next year. Figure out what weekday that is. Add days to that day until it matches your desired date. It's not that complicated, but it's harder than `strtotime('next Friday')`.

Comment: Technically it's not possible.  Consider this: next Friday is the 5th Friday in May.  The 5th Friday in May 2016 is June 3rd.  By which I mean, there is no 5th Friday in May 2016.  You should try a more general rule like the first Friday after the Xth day of the year.  It would probably be easier to code too.

Comment: See the edit on my answer, I think that will give you what you want!  It should go forward a year and find the *nearest* same weekday.  So if a year from now is a Saturday, it will go a year from now minus one day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, there may not be a 5th Friday in June, for example, so there needs to be some standard way to decide which week next year is the same week as the current one.

As it happens there is already a standard for week numbering in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) and PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/datetime) has built in functionality for handling them.

My suggestion would be to schedule the next meeting for the same day in the same `ISO 8601 week number` the following year. The following function will do that for you:-

```
/**
 * @param \DateTime $date Date of the original meeting
 * @return \DateTime Date of the next meeting
 */
function getSameDayNextYear(\DateTime $date = null)
{
    if(!$date){
        $date = new \DateTime();
    }
    return (new \DateTime())->setISODate((int)$date->format('o') + 1, (int)$date->format('W'), (int)$date->format('N'));
}
```

[See it working with some test code](http://3v4l.org/OtOYn).

I'm sure you'll agree that this is the simplest way of doing it and it should see you right for the [next 100 years or more](http://3v4l.org/3cLIS#v540) :)

References [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) and [Date](http://php.net/date) for formats.

Comment: +1, this answer isn't susceptible to creep like the other ones (like ... mine).  That is to say, it will always be the same time of the year, whereas "+1 year and next matching weekday" and "+1 year and closest matching weekday" (my two answers) will slowly creep toward the end and beginning of the year respectively.

Comment: Wow thanks! This works great! I'll explain to my employer about how weeks work (as you have explained it to me) and show him that this code works fine for an hundred years. Doubt he'll care much if they need to be manually set ONCE that far in the future :P

Comment: @Legacyblade glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you need. You'll need to thoroughly test it out to be sure, though.

```
$event = new DateTime('2014-05-18');
$dayOfWeek = $event->format('l');
if ($dayOfWeek !== 'Sunday') {
    $event->modify('previous Sunday'); 
}
else {
    $event->modify('-1 day'); 
}
$event->modify('+1 year');
if ($dayOfWeek !== 'Sunday' && $dayOfWeek !== $event->format('l')) {
    $event->modify('next ' . $dayOfWeek);
}
echo $event->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mIfLf8)

Comment: I test with `2014-06-30` and it returns  `2015-07-06`.

Comment: For some reason on that date it did not go forward exactly one year. I had to check to see if the day of the week matched before modifying it. Not sure why PHP handled that date that way and I'd like to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

So changing your requirements to "add a year and find the next matching day of the week" I've come up with this:

```
function nextDate($date = false){
    if(!$date){ $date = new DateTime(); }
    $oneYear = new DateInterval('P1Y');
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('w');
    $nextDate = clone $date;
    $nextDate->add($oneYear);
    $nextYearDayOfWeek = $nextDate->format('w');
    while($nextYearDayOfWeek != $dayOfWeek){
        // add a day and check again
        $nextDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $nextYearDayOfWeek = $nextDate->format('w');
    }
    return $nextDate;
}
```

And my tests:

```
$test1 = new DateTime('5/23/2014');
$test2 = new DateTime('5/24/2014');
$test3 = new DateTime('5/25/2014');
$test4 = new DateTime('5/26/2014');
$test5 = new DateTime('5/27/2014');
$test6 = new DateTime('5/28/2014');
$test7 = new DateTime('5/29/2014');
$test8 = new DateTime('1/1/2014');
$test9 = new DateTime('12/31/2014');
$test10 = new DateTime('5/5/2040');

$nextDate1 = nextDate($test1);
$nextDate2 = nextDate($test2);
$nextDate3 = nextDate($test3);
$nextDate4 = nextDate($test4);
$nextDate5 = nextDate($test5);
$nextDate6 = nextDate($test6);
$nextDate7 = nextDate($test7);
$nextDate8 = nextDate($test8);
$nextDate9 = nextDate($test9);
$nextDate10 = nextDate($test10);

print($nextDate1->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate2->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate3->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate4->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate5->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate6->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate7->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate8->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate9->format('m/d/y'));
print('<br />');
print($nextDate10->format('m/d/y'));
```

Results:

```
05/29/15
05/30/15
05/31/15
06/01/15
06/02/15
06/03/15
06/04/15
01/07/15
01/06/16
05/11/41
```

**Edit**

I've modified the function below to find the closest day of the week instead of the next one (though it tends to just be the same as the previous one except subtracting).

```
function nextDate($date = false){
    if(!$date){ $date = new DateTime(); }
    $oneYear = new DateInterval('P1Y');
    $dayOfWeek = $date->format('w');
    $nextDate = clone $date;
    $nextDate->add($oneYear);
    $nextYearDayOfWeek = $nextDate->format('w');
    $diff = $dayOfWeek-$nextYearDayOfWeek;
    // if $diff is more than 3, it's faster to go the other way
    if(abs($diff) > 3){
        if($diff > 0){
            $diff = $diff-7;
        }else{
            $diff = 7+$diff;
        }
    }

    if($diff != 0){
        if($diff < 0){
            $nextDate->sub(new DateInterval('P'.abs($diff).'D'));
        }else{
            $nextDate->add(new DateInterval('P'.$diff.'D'));
        }
    }

    return $nextDate;
}
```

Test results this time:

```
05/22/15
05/23/15
05/24/15
05/25/15
05/26/15
05/27/15
05/28/15
12/31/14
12/30/15
05/04/41
```